# server side socket io failed to emit event

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Event received in server-side but don't know why it not calling further function

```
       socket.on('user-chat', (data, callback) => {
                this.socket = socket;
                this.onUserChat(data, (response) => {
                    callback(response)
                });
        });
```

[image]

from the above screenshot, you can see that I'm receiving events(user-chat) on the server but my problem is that it does not return a response. can anyone suggest to me what is the issue behind this?
note : this issue happens vary really i mean 100 out of 1 time this issue occur

One more thing client socket closed unexectionally

Comment: @CodyＧ client side or server side?

Comment: Both, you should always catch your event based emitter errors --- otherwise it's an unhandled exception.

Comment: @CodyＧ can you provide a sample code line it really helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

Per an example for [socket.use](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#socket-use-fn)

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.use(([event, ...args], next) => {
    if (isUnauthorized(event)) {
      return next(new Error("unauthorized event"));
    }
    next();
  });

  socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("error", err); // I would add this
    if (err && err.message === "unauthorized event") {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  });
});
```

Then another example of catching client errors at [namespace.use](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api/#namespace-use-fn)

```js
// client-side
socket.on("connect_error", err => {
  console.log(err instanceof Error); // true
  console.log(err.message); // not authorized
  console.log(err.data); // { content: "Please retry later" }
});
```

Comment: @CodyG thanks i will trry in morning and let you know..

Comment: @CodyG all above line is already present in my code, a problem which I had noticed is that server receives event but it does not emit response back to the client. are there any bugs with the socket?

Comment: @CodyG from the above image you can see I m receiving user-chat event and also I use console.log inside user-chat method but it does not print anything

Comment: If it doesn't emit a response back to the client, perhaps the client disconnected? Are you able to reproduce the issue in a small, barebones repository? to me `client socket closed unexectionally` reads ... the browser tab closed or the socket timed out

Comment: @CodyG thanks for your help, finally found the issue when client connect to server require some time to load all serverside event in the client socket (freshly connected).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I resolve my bug. when client socket connect initially it requires some time to load all event of server.

sample code

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.use(([event, ...args], next) => {
    if (isUnauthorized(event)) {
       return next(new Error("unauthorized event"));
    }
    next();
 });

 socket.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("error", err); // I would add this
   if (err && err.message === "unauthorized event") {
     socket.disconnect();
   }
 });
 socket.emit("ready");
});
```

and in client-side use

```
 function clientSocket(){
  let  newSocket = io(base_url, socket_obj);
            newSocket.once('ready', () => {
                console.log("waiting for connection to complete");
                consectusChat.HideLoader();
                resolve(newSocket);
            })
            newSocket.on('connect', (socket) => {
                console.log("Connected");

            });
  }
```